# Адаптивная вёрстка блоков

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox

Есть некоторый html

```
<body>
    <div class="div"></div>
    <div class="div"></div>
</body>
```

Эти два блока на одной строке.
У первого блока минимальная длина 400px, у второго 200px. А максимальная длина у обоих ***должна быть*** 100%.
Как сделать так, чтобы при достижении минимальной длины, блок, который не вмещается, переносился на следующую строку. А предыдущий блок занимал 100%, оставшегося места на первой строке. При том перенесённый тоже занимал 100% пустого места на новой строке.

Прошу учесть, что блоков может быть и не два.
Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно решить через flexbox (если что задавайте `flex-grow` чтобы регулировать пропорции роста):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex__item {
  height: 40px;
}

.flex__item--one {
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex__item--two {
  min-width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex__item flex__item--one"></div>
  <div class="flex__item flex__item--two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему то у меня не работает ваш код, https://ibb.co/fcP6Nk

Comment: Да из [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dky0xd7), вот тестировал, должно работать.

Comment: Идеально! http://imgur.com/a/fijnS

Comment: как я понял на мобильниках работать не будет.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Большинство мобильных [с flexbox дружат](http://caniuse.com/flexbox/embed/description).

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/G78Pa

Comment: ↑ На мобильниках всё идеально

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan А что эта за ОС и браузер, где мой код не работает? Я просто не различаю Linux и Mac, если что.